# checking a serial number with jquery and regex

Tags: jquery, regex

If have one input field which is used to enter a serial number:

```
<div id="sn-check">    
    <input type="text" value="" name="sn" id="sn" size="30" maxlength="14">
</div>
```

My jQuery function looks like this:

```
(function(){    
    var snRegexp = /^[1-9][0-9][0-9][1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]([0][1-9]|[1][0-2])[0-9]{5}$/;

    $("#sn").on("keyup", function() {
        var text = $(this).val();
        var len = text.length;

        if(len == 14){
            var isMatch = snRegexp.test(text);
            if(isMatch){
                $("#sn-check").addClass("fine");
                $("#sn-check").removeClass("error")
            }else{
                $("#sn-check").addClass("error");
                $("#sn-check").removeClass("fine");
            }

        }else{
            $("#sn-check").removeClass("error");
            $("#sn-check").removeClass("fine");
        }
    });
}());
```

Okay, this function is working. All serial numbers in the following format are accepted:

- first three digits: all numbers from 100 - 999
- next 4 digits: a Year: 1000-2999
- next 2 digits: a month: 01 - 12
- last 5 digits: all numbers from 00000 - 99999

Eg: 25020130612345

If have four questions, to extend this script.

1. is the regex okay? are only the numbers I mentioned accepted?
2. The first three digits are only special numbers (e.g. 250, 273, 278, 312, 415) only these special numbers should be valid, all others make the serial number invalid. Is it possible to use an array for this numbers and pass it to the function checking the entered serials?
3. The last five digits should start at 0000**1** instead of 00000, how do i have to change my regex to do that?
4. it would be great to extend this function with a second regex value and another field. At the moment I have the posted jquery function 2 times and another var with a regex. How can I extend the function to work with more than 1 input field and more than 1 regex?

I made a fiddle to see my example working:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emjay__/aQ5Tv/2/)

Comment: I think will be more secure to check it on server side

Comment: I'm also checking it with PHP again after the form is submitted, but I'm highlighting the input after the number is entered.

Comment: @Edward I don't think this is meant as security, but as feedback to the user that the format of the serial is correct

Comment: Got it, just to be sure!

Comment: emjay,  will the user enter all the numbers in 1 field, ? will the separete them ? or you simply want to take a certain string or number and check the regix on it ?

Comment: Yes, the user will enter all numbers in 1 field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `join(separator)` method on the array, you can change the array of numbers to a group of possible id's in the pattern:

```
var numberArray = [250, 273, 278, 312, 415];
var snRegexp = new RegExp("/^(" + numberArray.join("|") + ")[12]\d{3}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(?!00000)\d{5}$/");
```

As for the third question, you should be able to use a lookahead in the pattern (something along the lines of `(?!00000)\d{5}`.

---

**Explanation**: `numberArray.join("|")` will take the array `numberArray`, and return a string containing all of the array's contents, separated by the string `|`. If you have the array `[250, 273, 278, 312, 415]`, this method will return the string `250|273|278|312|415`. In regular expressions, `(250|273|278|312|415)` means *Either 250, 273, 278, 312 or 415*.

`(?!00000)` is a **negative lookahead**. This means that the upcoming text can not equal `00000`. I use the negative lookahead to *exclude* a number from the `\d{5}` that would otherwise accept `00000`. Basically, `(?!00000)\d{5}` means *as long as this is not followed by 00000, accept any 5 digit number*.

Comment: Can you explain your Regex a little bit?

Comment: @emjay: I've edited my post and added explanations regarding the modified parts of the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your regexp looks okay to me, except that it can be shortened a bit by using [0-9]{2} instead of repeating it.
2. I would check this through code afterwards, instead of doing it throug regexps. You can use matching groups to get the specific 'fields' from the serial.
3. Same as #2, use javascript self instead of regexps to check that.
4. I would create an array object which maps field name to specific regexp. That way, you can retrieve the regexp to use from that object.

Comment: Also, `([0][1-9]|[1][0-2])` could be simplified to `(0[1-9]|1[0-2])`.

Comment: What do you mean by "matching groups"?

Comment: Any time you use () in regexps, so called matching groups are created. This allows you to extract specific data from the matched string.

Answer (score 2):

I think the logic of your javascript should be something like this.

```
 var regex = /(\d{3})([12]\d{3})([01][1-9])(\d{5})/,
     input = '25020130612345';

 if (input.match(regex)) {
     // you can now access each part of the input and validate it as you wish
     // e.g. RegExp.$1 will refers to 250, RegExp.$2 will refers to 2013
     if (isValidSpecialNumber(RegExp.$1)) {
         ..
     }
     ..
 }
```

Comment: What's the difference between [12] and [1-2] is it just shorter?

Comment: @emjay Yes, `()` splits those string in to groups.

Comment: Okay fine, why I can access the string with RegExp and not with regexp ? If I write regexp it doesn't work, but I've never defined RegExp

Comment: @emjay because Javascript it self is case-sensitive language. So that means `regex` will refer to some unintialized variable